# How can I see the details of the "ASP.NET HTTP Modules" in a Stackify trace?

Tags: stackify

[image: Stackify trace example]

We use [Stackify](https://stackify.com/) to monitor our SAAS application.
In a typical trace of a slow request we see that over 90% of the time is spent in "ASP.NET HTTP Modules".
It is nice to know, but we really do not know if there is a problem with the application, and if so what to do about it.

Is there a way or tool to drill in into the modules details using Stackify or some other tool?

Answer (score 2):

Here is the answer I received from Stackify support:

> Jun 1, 2020, 12:25:11 AM CDT
>
> Hi Dror,
>
> Thank you for reaching out to Stackify Support! Unfortunately, we won't be able identify the root cause for this delay - we just are able to show that something/somewhere along the pipeline is taking so much time (e.g. loading a module, or the module itself). This could be due to performance issues with a specific HTTP module. For example, something like a session provider querying SQL that is slow or causing bottlenecks.
>
> Our engineering team suggests that if this issue persists, you can try enabling Failed Request Tracing on the server in IIS. That enables pretty detailed tracing from the IIS pipeline steps that could help further troubleshoot the issue.
>
> Sorry if this isn't the most ideal answer. Let us know if you have other questions!
>
> Best Regards,
>
> Mark Quevedo | Developer Support Engineer

Answer (score 1):

The ASP.NET HTTP MODULES is a grouping of code that includes all incoming and outgoing requests that are a part of the HTTP Module within your application. As far as seeing a breakdown of the information included in this block of code you can do two things:

1. Sift through the Trace details to find any of the http requests
2. Use Prefix. This is a free tool Stackify offers (there is also a premium version you could add to your Retrace subscription) This will allow you to get more information in your traces as it works locally and in real time with your code. https://docs.stackify.com/docs/what-is-prefix

Comment: I  do not see the details in the trace. It displays a one liner "ASP.NET HTTP Modules". Hence the question. Can Prefix be used on the production environment?
This is where we have the performance problems.